# SICP Video Lecture 2

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I have a problem with this example

```
(define (+ x y)
  (if (= x 0)
      y
      (+ (-1+ x) (1+ y))))
```

What is the problem with -1+ and 1+, when i evaluate it i get this result

- DrScheme: -1+: this function is not defined
- racket  :  reference to undefined identifier: -1+

but i write this instead and it works

```
(define (add x y)
  (if (= x 0)
      y
      (+ (- x 1) (+ y 1))))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Racket:

- Use `add1` instead of `1+`
- Use `sub1` instead of `-1+` or `1-`

The trouble is, none of those names are standard, so you can't reliably use them across all Scheme implementations. :-)

Comment: sub1 and add1 are great, I think that Sussman use -1+ only to explain this example. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by adding SICP support to DrRacket.

http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/

Anymore trouble let me know.